# unobserved heterogeneity term in random effects model

Tags: panel-data, random-effects-model

In random effects model, we have a term that together with the idiosyncratic error, forms the error of the regression.
Do you have to include an actual variable there (for the term) or is it just there?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this depends on the software you are using, whether you have repeated measures, and what the unobserved heterogeneity relates to.

For example, In `lmer` in R, `+ (1 | id)` adds a random effect (intercept) for people with the same values on the id variable. In LIMDEP, nonparametric (latent class) random effect is added by adding `; LCM` to the syntax.

Comment: Can I not include a time-invariant variable in a random effects model?

Comment: Yes you can. The two examples I have provided in my answer are both time invariant. Time is just another variable (like ID).